# neo4j build failed due to TestRWLock test failure

Tags: neo4j

I am building neo4j after getting the source from github but the build failed due to test failures

Below are the sequence of steps i followed

#git clone https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j neo4j

#cd neo4j

#mvn clean install -DskipBrowser

Test failure results are below

Running org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TestRWLock

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 20.108 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TestRWLock
        testStressMultipleThreads(org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TestRWLock)  Time elapsed: 20.092 sec  <<< FAILURE!
        java.lang.AssertionError: null

```
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:64)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TestRWLock.testStressMultipleThreads(TestRWLock.java:366)
```

Comment: You might have found a bug, but why are you building the source? Did you fork the project and made a contribution? If you just want to use Neo4j, consider setting up a Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that it is just a flaky test: that the test makes assumptions that in rare situations *can* prove wrong. Please run it again to check if it works. Maven will tell you how to resume without building the entire thing from scratch, '-rf $SOMETHING'.

I did check our CI environment, we have had nothing but green builds for the last week for the master branch. Is your local copy up to date?

Also, please check you have a "certified setup", currently we support Maven 3+ and Oracle JDK 7 for master branch, on Linux, Windows and OSX. May I ask what your setup is?

Oh and lastly, I am as curious as the next guy: why *are* you building it locally? Most people download and use the server product from [our website](http://www.neo4j.org/download), others link to our artifacts in Maven Central.